# How to draw a line from lon/lat in Openlayers3

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, openlayers-3

How can i draw a Line in Openlayers 3?

I was able to draw one with this code:

```
var lineFeature = new ol.Feature(
                    new ol.geom.LineString([[-244780.24508882355, 5986452.183179816], [-1e6, 3e6]]));
```

But if i replace the coordinates with lon and lat coordinates, nothing happens.

In the API it says, i need a ol.coordinate Object for that...

Answer (score 0):

```
ol.proj.transform([7.520142, 53.803084], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

worked. Just found it out :D